# C++ - About template

Tags: c++, templates

When I use the template as below, the g++ will report error:

---

E32.cpp: In function ‘void display_vector(const std::vector&, std::ostream&, int)’:

E32.cpp:21:5: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector::const_iterator’ because ‘std::vector’ is a dependent scope
     vector::const_iterator 
     ^

---

```
template <typename elemType>                                                
void display_vector(const vector<elemType> &vec,
            ostream &os=cout, int len=8)
{
    vector<elemType>::const_iterator
        iter = vec.begin(),
        end_it = vec.end();
    int elem_cnt = 1;
    while(iter != end_it)
    {
        os << *iter++ << (!(elem_cnt++ % len)?'\n':' ');
    }
    os << endl;
}
```

Why? I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `typename` here:

```
typename vector<elemType>::const_iterator
```

Because `const_iterator` is a dependent name (which is also shown in the error message). Search this site to know more about dependent-name.

Better use `auto` and range-based for loop.